# Fix random mouse cursor movement in Fedora Gnome

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome3

I use Fedora 26 x64 (Gnome 3.24.2) and faced with some kind of ... a bug, as i think (i am not sure).

My mouse cursor suddenly moves to the corner of the screen (usually to the top left corner) when i work on my desktop (pc, monitor, mouse, keyboard). This happens few times per hour and makes me really mad. Cursor does not "freeze" just suddenly move to the screen corner. I run different programs on PC for example reading .pdf files or work with Libre Office when this bug take place so i can not find a dependence to any app.

Replacing monitor, mouse and keyboard by other devices return me the same result so my peripherals are OK. I think it a software bug (Gnome? Fedora?).

So my question is: how to fix this?

Comment: Are you using Wayland? If so, you might try to fall back to X11 and see if the problem is still there. You can do that when logging in: on the password screen, click in the gear icon and select "gnome on x11" (that's from memory, so it's approximate, but it should be close enough).

Comment: I also faced this issue few years back in `Kali Gnome`. It was driver compatibility issue with Gnome. Try switching to another Desktop Environment.

Comment: Yes, seems like i'm using wayland.        

`loginctl`
`SESSION        UID USER             SEAT             TTY`            
`c1         42 gdm              seat0            /dev/tty1`       
`6          0 root             seat0            /dev/tty2`       

`2 sessions listed.`
`# loginctl show-session 6 -p Type`
`Type=wayland`

Comment: I'll better try to change my desktop environment to other. Lets see will it fix problem or no.

Comment: I've switched to x11 today, but, unfortunately, it did not worked for me ((. So I've installed KDE Plasma then. No problem yet (4h). @Arpit Agarwal let me mark your post as solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also faced this issue few years back in `Kali Gnome`.

It was driver compatibility issue with `Gnome`.

Try switching to another Desktop Environment. I personally don't like `Gnome` and `KDE` because they comes with a bunch of dependencies.

I personally use `Xfce` because it is lightweight.